# Meaning of a C statement involving char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am working on an algorithm for a project and I ran across some code that I think may be helpful. However, as I try to read the code, I am having some difficulty understanding a statement in the code. Here is the code.

```
int firstWord[MAX_WORD_SIZE] = {0}, c = 0;

while (word1[c] != '\0') //word1 is char[] sent as a parameter
{
  firstWord[word1[c]-'a']++;
  c++;
}
```

I understand (I hope correctly) that the first line is setting up an integer array of my max size, and initializing elements to zero along with making the initial counter value "c" zero.

I understand that the while loop is looping through all of the characters of the `word1[]` array until it hits the final char `'\0'`

I am confused on the line `firstWord[word1[c]-'a']++;`
`word1[c]` should give a char, so what does doing the `-'a'` do? Does this cast the char to an integer which would allow you to access an element of the `firstWord[]` array and increment using `++`? If so, which element or integer is given by `word1[c]-'a'`

Comment: [**This table**](http://www.asciitable.com) may help you better understand that expression.

Comment: Look at the column marked `dec` next to the letters in the table. Then think about the math op being done (subtraction in this case).

Comment: Thanks, sorry I removed my comment as I figured out my question literally right after I asked you. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a program that counts the number of letters `a` to `z` from a word. The key point here is, `'a' - 'a'` has a value of `0`, and `'b' - 'a'` has a value of `1`, etc.

For instance, if `word1[c]` is the letter `'d'`, then `'d' - 'a'` is `3`, so it would increment `firstWord[3]`. When the word has been iterated character by character, `firstWord[3]` contains the number of letter `'d'` in the word.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response, just as a follow up question, would it be best then to have my array firstWord[] be set to have an initial size of 26 then rather than my MAX_WORD_SIZE which happens to be 30?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma Unless some characters following `'z'` in ASCII are also counted, I think you are right.

Answer (score 2):

**word1[c]-'a'** means the difference between the character in cth position of word1 and the integer value of 'a'. Basically it calculates the number of occurences of letters in a word.

So if word1[c] is 'b', then value of word1[c]-'a' will be ('b' - 'a') = 1. So the number of occurences of 'b' in the word will be incremented by 1.

Answer (score 1):

it seems this code is doing a letter count

1 so what does doing the -'a' do?

if word1[c] is 'a'  then word1[c]-'a' is 0

2 . Does this cast the char to an integer which would allow you to access an element of the firstWord[] array and increment using ++?

yes, it is integer promotion

3 .If so, which element or integer is given by word1[c]-'a'

if word1[c] is 'a'  then word1[c]-'a' is 0

Comment: Hi, see my previous edit to this answer for fixed formatting markdown.